# Using SWRevealViewController, If I swipe just 10% towards left, Then left view is displaying 90% and front view is displaying 10%

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

Using SWRevealViewController, If I swipe just 10% towards left, Then left view is displaying 90% and front view is displaying 10%, But it should not happen like this, If I swipe more than 30%, then only it should happen.

If I use **Rear,Front,Right** views, then I am not facing any issue, But  as per our requirement I am not using **Right** View, then I am facing this issue.

Please anyone help me to get rid of this issue. 
Thanks

Comment: I was tried [iOS-Slide-Menu](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu) before and it support that, for SWRevealViewController i think u have to implement it yourself